# How to handle multiple fast jQuery ajax submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on my website a checkbox list. Every time a box is clicked, an ajax script submits data to the server and saves the entry state in the database, then, on the done method, the box gets checked.

The main problem is when the user checks multiple boxes fast, most of them don't get checked, and worse, some are saved in the database, some are not, in a somewhat unpredictable manner.

Any insights on how to handle that? Is there something I could easily do to queue the requests, or maybe join all requests into a single one? I want something a bit like the google keep web interface.

Comment: when the user checks multiple boxes fast, most of them don't get checked.... Whats the point.? Only if is checked ajax will do its job right?

Comment: Add a timer in order to bundle the requests if the user clicks multiple times during an interval.

Comment: Is there something in browser debug console (eg firebug)? How long the update takes? Are you using sessions?

Comment: -4? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: @watcher: Nice solution. [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/tutorials/javascript) and [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/) are great references to practical JavaScript examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better user experience, I'd check the box immediately as the user clicks it, and let the request be sent to the server anonymously. Otherwise the user woul'd have to wait the round-trip time for visual feedback, which is generally not so great.

You can however easily implement a sort of queue:ing method that executes request "serially", like this. (warning untested)

```
var queue = [];
var processing = false;

function queueRequest(data, cb){
    // Queue data to be send to the backend
    // Also cb will be called after it's done
    queue.push({
        data: data,
        cb: cb
    });
    processQueue();
}

function processQueue(immediate) {
    // If we have an empty queue, we are done!
    if (queue.length === 0) {
        processing = false;
        return;
    }

    if (!processing || immediate) {
        var item = queue.shift();   // Take first item
        processing = true;

        // Send the ajax  request
        $.ajax({
            url: "backend.com/checks",
            data: item.data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(res) {
                if (typeof item.cb === "function")
                    cb(res);

                // Go on with the queue
                processQueue(true); // We call ourself, so it's "immediate"
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then you queue data to be sent like this:

```
queueRequest({checkbox:5}, function(res){
    // Check the checkbox here, or do w/e you want
    // ...
});
```

In a cool world I'd use promises instead of a callback, but this is a better example for the untrained JS-eye.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Polywhirl is right, don't send a single request for each action.  Instead, I would add a [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) function that will only fire once after `xxx` milliseconds have passed since the function was last called.

David Walsh's debounce function (linked to above):

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

You should be able to use it kinda like this:

```
var data = [];
var sendRequest = debounce(sendAjaxRequest, 200);

function sendAjaxRequest() {
    $.ajax({ /* Send Ajax Request */ });
    // Empty out the data array
    data = [];
}

// Add data to the array whenever your checkbox is clicked and 
// queue up the ajax request
$('.element').on('click', function() {
    data[] = $(this).data('my-data');
    sendRequest();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this scenario like so:

user checks box --> box gets checked --> ajax fires --> if response is success, keep checked; else, uncheck and display the error from the server response